# C++ 2d array using vectors returns a consistent incorrect result on the second query

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm doing a coding challenge where the aim is to take x arrays and query it y times. Each array is given a size (N) and a list of values and each query wants a specific value (b) from a specific array (a).

The input is given as follows:

```
X Y
N n n n ...
N n n n ...
a b
a b
```

Here is all of my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numArrays;
    int numQueries;
    scanf("%d %d", &numArrays, &numQueries);
    
    vector<int*> arrays;
    for (int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++)
    {
        int size;
        scanf("%d", &size);
        
        int arr[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
        }
        
        arrays.push_back(arr);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numQueries; i++)
    {
        int arr, ind;
        scanf("%d %d", &arr, &ind);
        printf("%d\n", arrays.at(arr)[ind]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The test input is 2 arrays and 2 queries given as follows:

```
2 2
3 1 2 3
5 9 8 7 6 5
0 1
1 3
```

The expected output should give **2** for the first query (which seems to be working fine) and then **6** for the second query however my actual output is this:

```
2
32767
```

Does anybody know why the second output comes out as **32767**. This seems to be a consistent value no matter what the arrays contain or what the second query is looking for. I think it's likely something to do with my vector declaration but I'm still relatively new to C++ so I'm not sure.

Comment: `arrays.push_back(arr);` will not work. `arr` is gone by the end of current loop iteration and you are left with a dangling pointer in the vector. Just use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: `int arr[size];` is not standard C++ anyhow. [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Why do you use vectors for dynamically sized array in one case but not in the other?

Comment: That's not a 2D array using vectors, it's a vector containing `numArrays` pointers, and all of them are invalid after the corresponding iteration. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. Get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (And spend some time reading about undefined behaviour.)

Comment: frankly, this code looks like you were using the wrong resources to learn C++. Non standard VLAs mixed with `std::vector`, pointless use of pointers, no C++ io, are all making it unecessarily compilcated (they arent completly wrong or "forbidden", but there is no good reason to do any of that in your code). If that is the way you learned code from somewhere, you should go elsewhere to learn. The link in the last comment has a list of good books.

Comment: `arrays.push_back(arr);` is the main mistake: You are adding pointers to an array on the stack into the vector. First, dynamically sized arrays on the stack are non-standard. Second, the pointers in your vector become invalid (undefined) once / each time you exit the `for` loop’s body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been already described in comments by others: You are storing a pointer to an array on the stack that will be undefined outside the `for` loop. Just use vectors for both array dimensions and let them handle pointers and memory allocations for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  size_t numArrays, numQueries;
  std::cin >> numArrays >> numQueries;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> arrays;
  arrays.reserve(numArrays);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numArrays; ++i) {
    size_t size;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> array;
    array.reserve(size);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      int number;
      std::cin >> number;
      array.push_back(number);
    }
    arrays.push_back(std::move(array));
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numQueries; ++i) {
    size_t arr, ind;
    std::cin >> arr >> ind;
    std::cout << arrays[arr][ind] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Admittedly, this lacks even the most basic error checking and error handling; it is simply a rewrite of the code from the question.

Of course you can handle the memory allocations yourself, but in that case you also need to make sure things get properly deallocated. (Again, the following example lacks error checking.)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

int main() {
  size_t numArrays, numQueries;
  std::cin >> numArrays >> numQueries;
  const auto arrays{
      std::make_unique_for_overwrite<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>(numArrays)};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numArrays; ++i) {
    size_t size;
    std::cin >> size;
    arrays[i] = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(size);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) std::cin >> arrays[i][j];
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numQueries; ++i) {
    size_t arr, ind;
    std::cin >> arr >> ind;
    std::cout << arrays[arr][ind] << std::endl;
  }
}
```